# How can i get 'activities' from two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, both of them have activity_id

for example:

```
class SectionAdvice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :contract
  has_many :lectures, dependent: nil
end

class Lecture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

i would like to do a query to get activities from them, its possible only to have a query? not two queries

my attempt is but i dont know how can i finish it, because to get from `SectionAdvice` i should to pass `contract_id` and in order to get from `Lecture` i should to pass `participant_id`

```
SectionAdvice.joins(:lectures).kept.where()
```

or should be like this (two queries) ?

```
a = SectionAdvice.kept.where('contract_id in ...')
b = Lectures.kept.where('participant_id = ...')

a.activities + b.activities
```

**Note 1:**
the activity model is

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :area
end
```

Comment: please show the relationships as defined in the Activity model

Comment: this is something that is fairly straightforward in SQL using a view with subqueries or a UNION.  Then you can use it as the basis for an active record model and get all the data with a single query.

Comment: @LesNightingill i just edited my question adding the model

Comment: the `Activity` model must contain relationships for `SectionAdvice` and `Lecture`, it's either `has_one` or `has_many`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are separate queries really an issue? As long as there are no joins in the data model it doesn't make sense to construct some in your queries.

From my understanding you are looking for the activities. You could do as following:

```
# select the activity_ids from SectionAdvice
a = SectionAdvice.kept.where('contract_id in ...').pluck("activity_id")   

#select the activity_ids from Lectures 
b = Lectures.kept.where('participant_id = ...').pluck("activity_id")          

# combine both arrays of activity_ids and select the corresponding Activities
activities = Activity.where(["id IN ?", a + b]).all
```

Pluck selects the specified field and creates an array of the values.

---

As pointed out in the comments you can use "UNION" to combine two queries. Maintaining a view might be difficult especially when you alter the table definition later. You can use UNION in Rails with the union gem:

```
gem 'active_record_union'
```

and then your query is something like

```
SectionAdvice.kept.where('contract_id in ...').activities.union(Lectures.kept.where('participant_id = ...').activities)
```

Have a look at https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union

Comment: how can i create an view with subqueries as said   
Les Nightingill in the comments

Comment: I doubt that going with a view yields better results. You can find the exact defintion in the documentation of your favourite RDBMS. You have to create one SELECT-Statement for the Activities (with JOIN to the contracts) and the contract_id, one SELECT-Statement (with JOIN to your lectures) and the lecture_id  in a different field than the contract and UNION both. Good luck :)